# Using wildcard to remove similar named files suffixed with number of multiple digits

Tags: regular-expression, wildcards

I have number of files with similar names suffixed with number from 1 to 500. I want to delete the files from 1 to 250 only. is there a way to do that using wildcard.

files are:
stdout.1 to stdout.500

I want to delete files from stdout.1 to stdout.250.

Thanks

Comment: Why not just `rm stdout.{1..250}`

Comment: Hi Inian, Thanks for this. I wasn't aware curly braces can be used for range. Its working. But few files are missing between 1 to 250 which shows the "No file or directory"  error. is there any way to execute only if its present. Just like it is performed with [0-9] when we use range in wildcard using [].

Comment: just add `-f`; gets rid of the message as well as ignores the missing files in setting the exit code.

Answer (score 8):

In Zsh, you could do just `rm stdout.<1-250>`. `<n-m>` matches parts of the filename that represent a decimal integer number from *n* to *m*. (Possibly with leading zeroes, so `stdout.0099` would also match.)

In Bash, you could use brace expansion: `rm stdout.{1..250}`. Though the difference with Zsh's `<1-250>` is that brace expansion generates strings without regard for existing files, so you may get errors if a file is missing from the middle of the list. In the case of `rm`, adding the `-f` option would silence those errors as with `-f`, `rm` only complains if any file you ask it to unlink would still be there after it returns.

If you want to avoid generating names of non-existing files, or are limited to standard `sh` (i.e. without brace expansion), then you'll have to do the matching character by character. So:

```
rm stdout.? stdout.??       #   1 to  99
rm stdout.1??               # 100 to 199
rm stdout.2[01234]?         # 200 to 249
rm stdout.250               # 250
```

However note that if there's no file that matches `rm stdout.2[01234]?`, that would end up removing a file called `stdout.2[1234]?` if it existed.

Comment: What's the difference between zsh's `<1-150>` and the bash's `{1..150}`? Does it only expand to the existing file names?

Comment: @terdon, zsh's `<1-150>` is a glob, so it only matches existing filenames. Also it seems to match leading zeroes, so `1` and `0001` both fit. Brace expansion just produces strings, they don't need to have matching existing files.

Comment: Note that `{1..250}` also comes from `zsh` (added in 1995). `bash` copied it (a subset initially) in 2004, ksh93 in 2005, yash in 2008. There are some variations between all 4 implementations, but they should all work the same for the simple case of `rm stdout.{1..250}`

Answer (score 3):

You can use [brace expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html#Brace-Expansion) for this

```
rm stdout.{1..500}
```

That command will be expanded to `rm stdout.1 stdout.2 ... stdout.500`. If some of the files don't exist, you will get an error message, but you can safely ignore that. Alternatively, you can redirect stderr so you don't see it:

```
rm stdout.{1..500} 2>/dev/null
```

Or, but this will be considerably slower, you can loop over the files and run `rm` on those that exist only:

```
for f in stdout.{1..500}; do
    [ -e "$f" ] && rm "$f"
done
```

You can also just delete all files whose name starts with `stdout.` and ends in one or more numbers:

```
rm stdout.[0-9]*
```

But that only works if you don't have files that match the pattern which you want to keep, since it will delete *all* files show name starts with `stdout.` followed by any number, so it will also delete files like `stdout.501` which aren't part of your range.

Comment: Hi terdon, I think it might be valuable to stress out that the last form, `rm stdout.[0-9]*`, would also remove `stdout.5X`, for example.

Comment: @Quasímodo fair enough. Done, thanks.

Comment: You're welcome. But `stdout.4` is part of his range, not? :)

Comment: @Quasímodo lol, I guess I should re-read the question before editing my answer! Thanks again :)

Comment: no need to redirect stderr or loop through each filename checking if it exists; just add `-f` to the `rm` command

Comment: @sitaram yeees, although that will also cause you to silently remove write-protected files. I prefer to avoid the nuclear option where possible.